# Booting to Ubuntu on dual boot (with Win 7) Desktop

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am a novice in Ubuntu. I followed the instructions on installing Ubuntu given on the website  next to my Win 7 and created a USB bootable stick. During the installation, I will choose "Install alongside with Win 7" option, so it will create the necessary partition for Ubuntu. Before I start the installation, I'd like to know whether it is going to create the necessary boot setup, or I have do this in Ubuntu after the installation using GRUB? That is, after the installation, when I boot, will I be able to either choose to login to Windows or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

With windows 7 installed first grub will detect windows for you and configure itself to Boot into windows. Problems only arise with Ubuntu installed first as windows boot loader overwrites grub and cannot detect the Ubuntu install.